# DB Transaction and Integrations Events dispatch - how to make it atomic?

Tags: asynchronous, queue, microservices, commit, atomic

I'm designing a system with multiple bounded contexts (microservices). I will have 2 kind of events.

- `Domain Events`, which happens "in memory" within single transaction (sync)
- `Integration Events,` which are used between bounded contexts (async)

My problem is, how to make sure that once transaction is committed (at this point I'm sure all `Domain Events` were processed successfully) that `Integration Events` are successful as well.

When my Transaction is committed, normally I will dispatch `Integration Events` (e.g. to the queue), but there is possibility that this queue is down as well, so previously just-committed transaction has to be "reverted". How?

The only solution that comes to my mind is to store `Integration Events` to the same DB, within the same Transaction, and then process the `Integration Events` records and push them to the queue - this would be something like "using current DB, as a pre-queue, before pushing it to **The Real Queue** (however I read that using DB for this is an anti-pattern).

Is there any pattern (reliable approach) to make sure both: **Transaction commit** and **Message pushed to the queue** is an atomic operation?

**EDIT**
After reading https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/domain-events-vs-integration-events-in-domain-driven-design-and-microservices-architectures/ , the author actually suggests the approach of "pre-queue" in same DB (he calls it “ready to publish the event”).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout [transactional outbox pattern](https://pradeeploganathan.com/patterns/transactional-outbox-pattern/).

This pattern does create a pre-queue. But the nice part is that pushing messages from pre-queue to real queue is fully decoupled. Instead you have a middleman called, a message relay that reads your transaction logs and pushes your event from to the real queue. Now since sending message and your domain events are fully decoupled, you can do all your domain events in a single transaction.

And make sure you that all your services are idempontent(same result despite duplicate calls). This transactional outbox patter does guarantee that messages are published, but in case when the message relay fails just after publishing(before acknowledging) it would publish the same event again.

Idempotent services is also necessary in other scenarios. As the event bus(the real queue) could have the same issue. Event bus propagates events, services acknowledge, then network error, then since the event bus is not acknowledged, the same event would be sent again.

Hmm actually idempotence alone could solve the whole issue. After the domain events computation completes(single transaction), if publishing message fails the service can simply throw an error without roll back. Since the event is not acknowledged the event bus will send the same event again. Now since the service is idempotent, the same database transaction will not happen twice, it will basically overwrite or better(should) skip and directly move to message publishing and acknowledging.

Comment: Idempotency is another aspect, but I agree is important. The pattern you described is actually same what I mention in question. The author of that pattern name it `OUTBOX` while I called it `pre-queue`. Thanks for confirming and thanks for sharing the link.